# How to make sure white space after 3 characters using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

Actually, I want to validate the Canadian  postal code form field using jQuery validation.

so i add the below  method to validate Canadian postal code

```
//Canada zipcode validation methode 
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("canadazipRegex", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTVXY]{1}[0-9]{1}[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]{1}[ ]?[0-9]{1}[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}$/i.test(value);
    }, "<br>You must enter your postal code in this format: A#A  #A#");
```

using this regular Expression

> ^[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTVXY]{1}[0-9]{1}[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]{1}[
>   ]?[0-9]{1}[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}$

the field should allow only this format

**A#A  #A#**

**like :A1A 1A1**

**Not like:A1A1A1**

So,How can i make sure white space after 3 characters.

I am not good with regular Expressions. if you give me good tutorial links also appreciated

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't have a solution to the regex problem, but from a UX standpoint I'd allow A1A1A1 and add the space on the server/with JavaScript. Nothing is more annoying than when a form forces you to do something it could very well do automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't make the space optional :

```
^[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTVXY][0-9][ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]\s[0-9][ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z][0-9]$
```

Also there are no needs to use quantifier `{1}`

Comment: +1 or as indicated in Juhana's comment, do make the spaces completely optional, and add them if they are missing; `^([ABCEGHJ-NPRSTVXY][0-9][ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z])\s*([0-9][ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z][0-9])$` and glue together the first and the second group with a space between them in your code.

Comment: @M42:very helpful,Thanks.But Couldn't understand Juhana's comment ,Could you explain.just for enthusiastic.

Answer (score 0):

\x20 matches will spaces. Try using that

Comment: :Sorry, I already said i'm not good with regexp .so please give me full regular expression to that.I dont know where to add